# Performing two queries in a single round trip to the database

Tags: c#, sql, linq, iqueryable

I have the following code to perform a full-text search. It creates a query, gets the total number of rows returned by that query and then retrieves the actual rows for only the current page.

```
// Create IQueryable
var query = from a in ArticleServerContext.Set<Article>()
            where a.Approved
            orderby a.UtcDate descending
            select a;

// Get total rows (needed for pagination logic)
int totalRows = query.Count()

// Get rows for current page
query = query.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * RowsPerPage).Take(RowsPerPage);
```

This works fine, but it requires two round trips to the database. In the interest of optimizing the code, is there any way to rework this query so it only had one round trip to the database?

Comment: In my opinion No. If you don't want to store all rows in memory of course.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in one round trip, only way I can think of is to rethink your pagination to work without having to get a total count

Comment: Completely agree with @JanR. The only way to achieve that is to use pagination in one query. If result query returns `null`, then there's no data to show.

Comment: You wrote that you need `totalRows` variable for pagination logic, but it seems you never use it.

Comment: @MaciejLos: That's not an option. I am able to create a richer UI/UX when the page knows how many total rows there are. I'd like to optimize, but I'm not willing to give up on features. (I didn't see a need to show how I use `totalRows`. I do use it.)

Comment: OK. Seems there's no option to achieve that in one round trip. I think you need to use 2 queries: 1) to return total no. of records `var totalRows = ArticleServerContext.Set<Article>().Where(a=>a.Approved).Count()` and 2) to return collection of Articles (your query together with pagination as one query). This solution might be bit faster, becasue of ordering data is ignored...

Comment: The simplest form of first query will be: `var totalRows = ArticleServerContext.Set<Article>().Count(a=>a.Approved);`

Comment: Generally speaking, then unless the network is a problem  - I'd say that there are likely other places where you can optimize much more cost/effective than worrying about an extra roundtrip to the database. Especially as you can easily cache a value like this to avoid having to call it each time.

Comment: @MaciejLos if you do `select count(*) from TableName order by columnName` - SQL Server (I presume are talking about it here, but other engines will have this too) is clever enough to ignore ordering anyway, so this is not an optimisation.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen: The number of articles won't change very often, but it will change. I don't see how you can cache this value.

Comment: @JonathanWood easiest would be to save it for the current session if it is very volatile or just for the current 'version' of the list if the filtering of the list can cause different results; and then just save it for a short time, if session is too long. If not, you could just cache it and invalidate the cache when data changes happen in the database either via dependency check and/or notification patterns or other similar patterns. It shouldn't be much work as I see it, but the specifics is dependant on your exact situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can perform this two operations with the help of the only one query to database:

```
// Create IQueryable
var query = from a in ArticleServerContext.Set<Article>()
            where a.Approved
            orderby a.UtcDate descending
            select new { a, Total = ArticleServerContext.Set<Article>().Where(x => x.Approved).Count() };

//Get raw rows for current page with Total(Count) field
var result = query.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * RowsPerPage).Take(RowsPerPage).ToList();

//this data you actually will use with your logic 
var actualData = result.Select(x => x.a).ToList();

// Get total rows (needed for pagination logic)
int totalRows = result.First().Total;
```

If you use MSSQL `query` wil be look that way:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[UtcDate] AS [UtcDate], 
    [Extent1].[Approved] AS [Approved],     
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM  [dbo].[Articles] AS [Extent1]
    CROSS JOIN  (SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Articles] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE [Extent2].[Approved] ) AS [GroupBy1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Approved]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[UtcDate] DESC
```

Comment: Well, yeah. Let's pull all data through the network just to throw it away. Code like that is the reason some programs are awfully slow.

Comment: All data, are you sure? I only take one additional column. And query not use subqueries for each row to calculate Count - instead simple join with the only one row.

Comment: I don't see where you are loading all the data. I have to wonder, though, how SQL Server handles calculating the count of the entire set with each row. Perhaps it's able to optimize that out.

Comment: `var result = ...`- it is place where I load all data. And SQL Server not calculate Count() for each row in set separately, it calculate it **the only one time** (`SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1] FROM [dbo].[Articles]`) and then join this one number to all rows in set, look more carefully at t-sql script at the end of my answer.

Comment: As far as I can see - the SQL behind this should work. The main issue with this - generally speaking - is that the more complex your queries become, the more complex the 'inner query' will also be which can make it nasty to write (but that goes for all pagination logic). But for this specific question, this should indeed work.

Comment: The main issue with this is that it is not equivalent to the original - you are counting the whole table while the original is counting the query.

Comment: Thanks to @IvanStoev, answer was fixed.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov: Your query returns the number of total rows with _each_ result. That is more than once. But, again, perhaps it's smart enough to only perform the calculation ones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it's worth enough, but it's doable under the following constraints:

(1) `CurrentPage` and `RowsPerPage` are not affected by the `totalRows` value.
(2) The query is materialized after applying the paging parameters.

The trick is to use `group by` constant value, which is supported by EF. The code looks like this:

```
var query = 
    from a in ArticleServerContext.Set<Article>()
    where a.Approved
    // NOTE: order by goes below
    group a by 1 into allRows
    select new
    {
        TotalRows = allRows.Count(),
        PageRows = allRows
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.UtcDate)
            .Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * RowsPerPage).Take(RowsPerPage)
    };

var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
var totalRows = result != null ? result.TotalRows : 0;
var pageRows = result != null ? result.PageRows : Enumerable.Empty<Article>();
```